# Changing array values from one array to another

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on a Java assignment for CS class. 
I am having issues transferring values from one user-defined array to another. 
I am able to transfer an array to another method but I cannot get the values of the array to agree to the parameters of the second array. 
Thank you for helping.

```
    import java.util.*;
    import java.io.IOException;
    public class HW5_1{ 
    public static void transpose(int mn[][]) throws IOException
    {
     Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
     int i, j;
     int nm[][] = new int [5][3];
     for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
     for(j = 0; j < 3; j++){
     nm[i][j]= mn[j][i];
    }
    System.out.println(nm[i][j]+ "   " + "/n");}
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{ 

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("How many rows?");
    int row = keyboard.nextInt();

    System.out.println("How many columns?");
    int column = keyboard.nextInt();

    //Create array 
    int [][] mn = new int[row][column];

    //Create variables
    int i,j = 0;

    //For loops to receive input
    for(i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
     for (j = 0; j < column; j++)
     {   
      System.out.println("Enter the numbers: ");
      mn[i][j] = keyboard.nextInt();
     }
    }
   transpose(mn);
    //Moves array to transpose method
  }
}
```

I would get this answer:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at HW5_1.transpose(HW5_1.java:19)
    at HW5_1.main(HW5_1.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:267)
```

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: I did get an error when putting in values. java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
 at HW5_1.transpose(HW5_1.java:19)
 at HW5_1.main(HW5_1.java:47)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:267)
>

Comment: can you provide that in your answer too?

Comment: updated question with output error

Comment: I added a throw IO exception to both methods but I got that error.

Comment: look at my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in your `transpose`-method you want your `System.out.println(nm[i][j]+ "   " + "/n");` inside the for loop. Also you have a lot of stuff that isn't needed in your method. E.g. the `throws` declaration, but also the `keyboard` variable.

Then you have some static declarations like the `5` and `3` as rows respectively columns. This can be skipped by dynamically reading the value from the input array.

At last you don't need the `i` and `j`  variable outside your loops so you can scope them inside.

So the cleaned up method would look like this:

```
public static void transpose( int mn[][] ){
    int nm[][] = new int[mn[0].length][mn.length]; // use the values from mn
    for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ){
        for( int j = 0; j < 3; j++ ){
            nm[i][j] = mn[j][i];
            System.out.println(nm[i][j] + "   " + "/n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: However, I now have another issue. When I get my output, It lists all of the integers in a line. How can I fix it so each column gets it's own line of output?  Here's my output as an example: 1 6 11 2 7 12 3 8 13 4 9 14 5 10 15. My output should be 1 6 11 /n 2 7 12 /n 3 8 13 /n 4 9 14 /n 5 10 15 /n, the /n standing for new line.

Comment: @NateTulchinsky when do you output *what*?

Comment: If I set my array to 3 rows and 5 columns, and enter the numbers 1-15 as my input, I get the output listed in my previous comment.

Comment: Then you'd have to print your array outside of the loops

Comment: I got the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have a fixed size in your new array:

```
int nm[][] = new int [5][3];
```

Make it to variable using the dimensions of your original array:

```
public static void transpose(int mn[][]) throws IOException {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i, j;
    int nm[][] = new int [mn.length][mn[0].length];
    for(i = 0; i < mn.length; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < mn[0].length; j++){
            nm[i][j]= mn[j][i];
        }
        System.out.println(nm[i][j]+ "   " + "/n");
    }
}
```